# Add header to CSV without loading CSV

Tags: python, csv

Is there a way to add a header row to a CSV without loading the CSV into memory in python? I have an 18GB CSV I want to add a header to, and all the methods I've seen require loading the CSV into memory, which is obviously unfeasible.

Comment: Did you try the writeheader method of DictWriter? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
I don't know the exact answer, just an idea: If you open the file with 'a' and try to use the writeheader, would it work?
It would be good if you would do this trying with a copy of the original file, if there is something wrong.

Comment: See the updated answer for a speed comparison of the 3 methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the fact that `csv` module iterates on the rows, so it never loads the whole file in memory

```
import csv

with open("huge_csv.csv") as fr, open("huge_output.csv","w",newline='') as fw:
    cr = csv.reader(fr)
    cw = csv.writer(fw)
    cw.writerow(["title1","title2","title3"])
    cw.writerows(cr)
```

using `writerows` ensure a very good speed. The memory is spared here. Everything is done line-by-line. Since the data is properly processed, you could even change the separator and/or the quoting in the output file.

Answer (score 11):

You will need to rewrite the whole file. Simplest is not to use python

```
echo 'col1, col2, col2,... ' > out.csv
cat in.csv >> out.csv
```

Python based solutions will work at much higher levels and will be a lot slower. 18GB is a lot of data after all. Better to work with operating system functionality, which will be the fastest.

Comment: And if you don't want to leave Python, you can always wrap this in a `subprocess.call()` call. Or even do the writing of the first line in Python like in the answer by @maximilian-peters.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a comparison of the three suggested solutions for a ~200 MB CSV file with 10^6 rows and 10 columns (n=50).
The ratio stays approximately the same for larger and smaller files (10 MB to 8 GB).

> cp:shutil:csv_reader 1:10:55

i.e. using the builtin `cp` function is approximately 55 times faster than using Python's `csv` module.

Computer:

- regular HDD
- Python 3.5.2 64-bit
- Ubuntu 16.04
- i7-3770

[image]

---

```
import csv
import random
import shutil
import time
import subprocess

rows = 1 * 10**3
cols = 10
repeats = 50

shell_script = '/tmp/csv.sh'
input_csv = '/tmp/temp.csv'
output_csv = '/tmp/huge_output.csv'
col_titles = ['titles_' + str(i) for i in range(cols)]

with open(shell_script, 'w') as f:
    f.write("#!/bin/bash\necho '{0}' > {1}\ncat {2} >> {1}".format(','.join(col_titles), output_csv, input_csv))

with open(shell_script, 'w') as f:
    f.write("echo '{0}' > {1}\ncat {2} >> {1}".format(','.join(col_titles), output_csv, input_csv))
subprocess.call(['chmod', '+x', shell_script])

run_times = dict([
    ('csv_writer', list()),
    ('external', list()),
    ('shutil', list())
])

def random_csv():
    with open(input_csv, 'w') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for i in range(rows):
            csv_writer.writerow([str(random.random()) for i in range(cols)])
    with open(output_csv, 'w'):
        pass

for r in range(repeats):
    random_csv()
    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/41982368/2776376
    start_time = time.time()
    with open(input_csv) as fr, open(output_csv, "w", newline='') as fw:
        cr = csv.reader(fr)
        cw = csv.writer(fw)
        cw.writerow(col_titles)
        cw.writerows(cr)
    run_times['csv_writer'].append(time.time() - start_time)

    random_csv()
    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/41982383/2776376
    start_time = time.time()
    subprocess.call(['bash', shell_script])
    run_times['external'].append(time.time() - start_time)

    random_csv()
    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/41982383/2776376
    start_time = time.time()
    with open('header.txt', 'w') as header_file:
        header_file.write(','.join(col_titles))

    with open(output_csv, 'w') as new_file:
        with open('header.txt', 'r') as header_file, open(input_csv, 'r') as main_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(header_file, new_file)
            shutil.copyfileobj(main_file, new_file)
    run_times['shutil'].append(time.time() - start_time)

    print('#'*20)
    for key in run_times:
        print('{0}: {1:.2f} seconds'.format(key, run_times[key][-1]))

print('#'*20)
print('Averages')
for key in run_times:
    print('{0}: {1:.2f} seconds'.format(key, sum(run_times[key])/len(run_times[key])))
```

---

If you really want to do it in Python, you could create the header file first and then merge it with your 2nd file via [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).

```
import shutil
with open('header.txt', 'w') as header_file:
    header_file.write('col1;col2;col3')

with open('new_file.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    with open('header.txt', 'r') as header_file, open('main.csv', 'r') as main_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(header_file, new_file)
        shutil.copyfileobj(main_file, new_file)
```

Comment: This benchmark can't be right. Finishing in 0.13 seconds means reading and writing at 1538 MB/s simultaneously. A "regular HDD" can't do that. Probably the file system needs to be flushed.

Comment: @Wups: Thanks for checking! I'll run the benchmarks and try to make everything's flushed.