# Fastest way to stack CSV files

Tags: python, bash, csv, append

I have 10 csv files with the same exact columns and data types.  What is the fastest/most efficient way to stack them?

CSV1:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
  1  |  'a' |  0.1
  2  |  'b' |  0.8
```

CSV2:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
  3  |  'c' |  0.4
  4  |  'd' |  0.3
```

I could read them in with `Pandas` and repeat `df.append` but that seems slow since I have to read everything into memory and if the files are very large that can take quite a while.  Wondering if I can do it faster using either bash commands or some other Python package.

I would prefer not to use something that had any heavy dependencies or required a compile.

P.S.  Bonus points if the solution COULD also automatically handle columns that exist in one dataset and not another.

Comment: you want to create 1 big csv file with all the data right?

Comment: there's something similar (not using pandas) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982238/add-header-to-csv-without-loading-csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `head` and `tail`

```
head -n1 a.log > output.log
for f in a.log b.log; do tail -n+2 $f; done >> output.log
```

If your input files might have no newline at the end, you have to add it manually as @zwar noted. Many solutions for this problem are given [in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file). My favorite that works in this context is

```
head -n1 a.log > output.log
for f in a.log b.log
do
  tail -n+2 $f
  [ -n "$(tail -c1 $f)" ] && echo ""
done >> output.log
```

Comment: Be careful with this one (just as with head/sed one) - if any of your CSV files (except the last one) doesn't have a line break at the last row (perfectly legal for a CSV), this will mess up the output.

Comment: @zwer thanks for the hint! I added a solution for that problem

Comment: `tail -c1 "$f"` is always going to output a single byte (unless the file is completely empty), whether or not that byte is (part of) a line-ending sequence.

Comment: @chepner yes, it does, but test will handle those results differently

Comment: The second command is wiping out the contents (aside from the header) in `b.log` on my test case.  `head -n1 csv1.csv > csv2.csv;
for f in csv1.csv csv2.csv;
do;
  tail -n+2 $f;
  [ -n "$(tail -c1 $f)" ] && echo "";
done >> out_csv.csv`

Comment: @koalo Ah, right, the command substitution strips the newline.

Comment: @Chris You should not pipe the header to the csv2.csv, but the out_csv.csv

Comment: @koalo Thanks!  That fixed it.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

> As @zwer correctly noted in a [comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329494/fastest-way-to-stack-csv-files/42329657#comment71812091_42329674) this solution will not work correctly if the input CSVs miss the newline symbol at the last line.

---

A solution using `bash` and `sed` (assuming that all files have the same columns/separators and all of them containing the header line):

**concat_csv_files**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

head -n1 "$1"
for f do
    sed -e 1d "$f" # or: tail -n+2 "$f"
done
```

Example:

```
concat_csv_files csv* > stacked.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Python solution:

```
csv_in = ["csv1.csv", "csv2.csv"]  # paths of CSVs to 'concentrate'
csv_out = "output.csv"

skip_header = False
with open(csv_out, "w") as dest:
    for csv in csv_in:
        with open(csv, "r") as src:
            if skip_header:  # skip the CSV header in consequent files
                next(src)
            for line in src:
                dest.write(line)
                if line[-1] != "\n":  # if not present, write a new line after each row
                    dest.write("\n")
            skip_header = True  # make sure only the first CSV header is included
```

For merging data with differentiating number of columns you'll have to at least partially parse your CSVs.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to do a python solution

```
import csv

my_files = ['file_one.csv', 'file_two.csv']
final_file = []
for fi in files:
     with open(fi, r) as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
          for row in reader:
               final_file.append(row)

#write out final file
with open('final_file.csv', 'w') as out:
    for line in final_file:
         out.write('|'.join(line))
         out.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another pure Python solution. The idea is to use glob to build a list of files to process, then import them individually into individual pandas dataframes (and add each dataframe to a list). Then concatenate the list of dataframes into one. You only want to do this once, not using repeated df.append calls (it's too slow).  I found that specifying the datatype for each column helped to speed things up.

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def process_csv_file(f):

    print("Processing file {}".format(f))

    # check if it's an empty file (have to be able to append an empty dataframe)
    # specifying the datatypes speeds up the process because pandas doesn't have to guess.
    if os.stat(f).st_size > 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, sep = ',', dtype = {'col1' : str, 'col2' : float}, memory_map=True)
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame()

    return(df)

csv_files = glob.glob(indir +'/**/' + '*.csv', recursive = True)
print ("Found {} files to parse.".format(len(csv_files)))
frames = [process_csv_file(f) for f in csv_files]

csv_df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: This one is a problem if the entirety of the data doesn't fit into memory whereas the others stream the data.  I didn't realize that the iterative append was slower than a concat though!

Comment: Very true. When I first wrote this my goal was to build a dataframe with all the contents so I could do further pandas manipulations. Only peripherally related to your request.