# Add headers using System Shell command through R

Tags: r, cmd

I found a way to use `cmd` to add a header record to a file:

```bat
@echo off    
echo group  id  firstname   lastname   homephone > new.csv
type old.csv >> new.csv
```

I want to run this in `R` using `system()`, but I get a `status code 127` error.

How can I get this command to run?

Comment: Why not just use R for this? (i.e. no `system()` / `system2()`) Also, you have no commas in your `echo` but seem to claim this is a CSV file.

Comment: I literally copied this from another StackOverflow question...they used .csv, but I tried with "," and didn't work.  The issue is that this is a 16GB file, and it makes no sense to load into R to then rewrite it out.  I am looking to use native OS efficiency.

Comment: O_o Um… `stringi::stri_read_lines` is as fast or faster than Windows  `type`; facts matter. And "it makes sense to spawn a new process but not use R without that extra bit of work" is also kind of weird to say. But, good luck to you.

Comment: To add context, we have a dynamic system that uses R in loops for other components of the process, so if R could then execute system commands, it would help.  I also run into a memory issue within R, and am hoping the system command wouldn't.  I could be wrong...I am trying to learn

Comment: Also, take a look at the 2nd answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982238/add-header-to-csv-without-loading-csv

Comment: a) according to R docs, stri_read_lines is an "experimental function"
b) according to the interwebs, stri_read_lines cannot handle large datasets as well as readLines or fread

Comment: Well, it's used in production in thousands or orgs; it can handle large datasets provided you've got the RAM; `readLines()` is slow and horribad; `fread` is for CSV files not straight line reading. And, i'm officially done with this q. Again, good luck to you.